# I can't get my .show to work when trying to display more text in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to stop users seeing a wall of text and break it up into three buttons that will hide the buttons and reveal additional information. The problem I have is my button only hides itself (Which I want) but the text I want to show is always on display already. I have tried playing with the class and the id of the `<p>` that I want to show but this doesn't help does anyone know why? I have an example below. Any help would be appreciated

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(" button ").click(function(){
        $("button").hide();
    });
    $(" button ").click(function(){
        $(".2").show(); 
    });
    
});
```

```css
#2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xl sr-button" id="click">Tell me more</button>

<p class="2">When you buy something on a Credit Card all your transactions from one month will be bundled together into a statement and you will be asked to clear at least some of the debt off which is called a “Minimum payment” this however will mean that you will start to be charged interest on your balance. If you clear the balance in full however you will not be charged and get to benefit from things such as additional protection from fraud and any rewards your card offers. You can set up a direct debit to clear the balance every month so that you don’t forget.</p><br>

<p class="2">Credit Cards can be a great way to build your Credit Score as if you spend within your limits and clear the balance you will prove that you are able to manage your money by not overspending and this will have a positive effect on trying to obtain credit in the future such as a loan or a mortgage. </p><br>

<p class="2">Some cards come with interest free periods when you take out a card where you will only need to pay the minimum balance for the first few months but then if you do not clear the remaining balance you will be charged interest which is usually around the 17% mark so this is not cheap. Credit Cards are incredibly flexible and useful tools if used responsibly if you run up a balance on a Credit Card that you are unable to clear it may be worth using a feature called a Balance Transfer to a card that has an interest free period you will still need to make the minimum payment but this can be a much cheaper way to repay the debt. </p><br>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: off-topic, but your css is targeting an element with an id of '2', which doesn't exist in your html. did you mean `.2 { ... }`?

Comment: also, css doesn't like classes and ids that start with a number. consider renaming it to `.two` instead

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you want to hide the text initially, and show it when the button is clicked? This should work for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // hide the paragraphs initially
  $(".two").hide();
  
  // when the button is clicked, hide it and show the paragraphs
  $('#click').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".two").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.two {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xl sr-button" id="click">Tell me more</button>

<p class="two">When you buy something on a Credit Card all your transactions from one month will be bundled together into a statement and you will be asked to clear at least some of the debt off which is called a “Minimum payment” this however will mean that you will
  start to be charged interest on your balance. If you clear the balance in full however you will not be charged and get to benefit from things such as additional protection from fraud and any rewards your card offers. You can set up a direct debit to
  clear the balance every month so that you don’t forget.</p>
<br>

<p class="two">Credit Cards can be a great way to build your Credit Score as if you spend within your limits and clear the balance you will prove that you are able to manage your money by not overspending and this will have a positive effect on trying to obtain credit
  in the future such as a loan or a mortgage.</p>
<br>

<p class="two">Some cards come with interest free periods when you take out a card where you will only need to pay the minimum balance for the first few months but then if you do not clear the remaining balance you will be charged interest which is usually around the
  17% mark so this is not cheap. Credit Cards are incredibly flexible and useful tools if used responsibly if you run up a balance on a Credit Card that you are unable to clear it may be worth using a feature called a Balance Transfer to a card that has
  an interest free period you will still need to make the minimum payment but this can be a much cheaper way to repay the debt.</p>
<br>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

An alternative approach would be to hide the text first with CSS, like this:

`.two {display: none;}`

or:

`<p class="two" style="display: none;">`

and just have the `.click()` call in your javascript.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do I thought maybe there was some kind of defining I had to do in CSS or HTML to make this possible I didn't see a way to define it's initial state in JQuery, thanks!

Comment: @CallumK no problem! a valid alternative would be to hide the text with css first, see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

For one, classes cannot start with numbers. So after you fix that, you can just add `display:none` to the class and be done.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(".two").show(); 
    });
});
```

```css
.two {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xl sr-button" id="click">Tell me more</button>

<p class="two">When you buy something on a Credit Card all your transactions from one month will be bundled together into a statement and you will be asked to clear at least some of the debt off which is called a “Minimum payment” this however will mean that you will start to be charged interest on your balance. If you clear the balance in full however you will not be charged and get to benefit from things such as additional protection from fraud and any rewards your card offers. You can set up a direct debit to clear the balance every month so that you don’t forget.</p><br>

<p class="two">Credit Cards can be a great way to build your Credit Score as if you spend within your limits and clear the balance you will prove that you are able to manage your money by not overspending and this will have a positive effect on trying to obtain credit in the future such as a loan or a mortgage. </p><br>

<p class="two">Some cards come with interest free periods when you take out a card where you will only need to pay the minimum balance for the first few months but then if you do not clear the remaining balance you will be charged interest which is usually around the 17% mark so this is not cheap. Credit Cards are incredibly flexible and useful tools if used responsibly if you run up a balance on a Credit Card that you are unable to clear it may be worth using a feature called a Balance Transfer to a card that has an interest free period you will still need to make the minimum payment but this can be a much cheaper way to repay the debt. </p><br>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```